# How do I change sign-up fee text in WooCommerce Subscriptions?

Tags: php, woocommerce, subscriptions

So far i've tried adding the following code to my functions.php with no luck:

```
<?php
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Sign-up Fee' :
            $translated_text = __( 'bin deposit', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' );
            break;
        case 'Apply Coupon':    
            $translated_text = __( 'Enter Coupon', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
?>
<?php
function my_signupfee_string( $pricestring ) {

    $newprice = str_replace( 'sign-up fee', 'bin deposit', $pricestring );
return $newprice;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_sign_up_fee', 'my_signupfee_string' );
?>
```

Neither of these functions are working and I am new to changing the internals of a plugin like Subscriptions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! So how are they not working? What is the result? Are there errors? It is easier to help when given more information about how it is failing.

Comment: Removing excess tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the price string in woocommerce subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118763/how-do-i-change-the-price-string-in-woocommerce-subscriptions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong filter. The `woocommerce_subscriptions_sign_up_fee` filter is for changing the actual number only. The `gettext` filter is about translating strings.

Try this:

```
function change_subscription_product_string( $subscription_string, $product, $include )
{
    if( $include['sign_up_fee'] ){
        $subscription_string = str_replace('sign-up fee', 'something else', $subscription_string);
    }
    return $subscription_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'change_subscription_product_string', 10, 3 );
```

In my example this changed the string:

**'$111.10 / month for 5 months with a 3-month free trial and a $22.00 sign-up fee'**

into

**'$111.10 / month for 5 months with a 3-month free trial and a $22.00 something else'**

The `woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string` filter is located in `class-wc-subscriptions-product.php` in the function `get_price_string()`.

Comment: This is correct, however I would like to suggest to include a conditional statement `if ( $include['sign_up_fee'])`. So that it would not try to replace what is not there ;)

Comment: Is this usable for changing the string text "month" (the period of the subscriptions? @Reigel